# Putting Custom CSS into Laravel 6

Tags: css, laravel

I put my css in the public folder and linked to it in my template, but the css won't work. When I run the file out of Laravel using HTML index, it works fine. But, when I put it in Laravel it won't see the css.

This is my code in the template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media.css">
```

Do I need to add anything to make it blade/laravel specific?

Comment: What is the folder structure in your public folder?

Comment: You can use one of the helpers that comes with Laravel e.g. `url()` or `asset()` (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#urls) or for a more basic solution you can add a `/` to the beginning of the path

Answer (score 2):

use `asset` like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/media.css')}}">
```

read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-asset) for more info!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it was a browser issue. All of my css and links were correct and the files were in the correct location. It worked in Safari, but not in Firefox. I had to correct a few things on my preferences in Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

can you confirm the CSS files are not reached by the browser ?
If not, maybe the css folder is not in your public folder :
public/css/style.css
This way it should works fine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead); instead, provide [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) that don't require clarification from the asker.